# round corners no javascript or css3

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I have a nav menu in which the hover state of a link looks like this,

[image]

As you can see there is a rounded corner background set upon an orange background. The client has requested that this works right through the IE6 (they are not at the stage where they can upgrade yet).  Now I came into web-development quite recently so I have not learnt old techniques for achieving this effect could some enlighten me please? Below is my code, currently I am using CSS3.

```
#navPrimary {
        background:#de4702;
        height:37px;
        margin:0px auto;
        width:517px;
        padding:5px 0px 0px 0px;
        display:block;
        overflow:hidden;
    }

        #navPrimary li {
            width:252px;
            float:left;
            display:block;
            height:100px;
            list-style-type:none;
            text-align:center;
            margin:0px 0px 0px 8px;
        }

            #navPrimary li.first {
                width:67px;
                padding:0px 14px 0px 14px;
                display:block;
                margin:0;
            }

            #navPrimary .last {
                width:154px;
            }

            #navPrimary li a {
                color:#fff;
                font-weight:bold;
                text-decoration:none;
                display:block;
                height:27px;
                padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;

            }

                #navPrimary li a:hover {
                    color:#de4702;
                    background:#fff;
                    -moz-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
                    -webkit-border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
                    border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
                }

<ul id="navPrimary">

      <li class="first"><a href="/" title="#request.sitename# | Home">Home</a></li>

      <li><a href="##" title="Free Admission">Free Admission </a></li>

      <li class="last"><a href="#request.public_vroot#index.cfm?fuseaction=game.terms" title="Terms &amp; Conditions">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: They can't upgrade from IE6? Just download Firefox! It's the most advanced version of IE *to-date*!

Comment: I don't think you can do it with css for IE6. You're going to have to use images.

Answer (score 5):

The technique to achive this is called **Sliding Doors**. Read more about it [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/).
It's basically about using images at two elements (two parts of a door).. one at the left side and another at the right side.

Comment: jinx :p you were 47 seconds faster

Answer (score 2):

It will take a few spans and images but you can get the same affect using the css sliding door technique. Check out this list apart article here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Answer (score 1):

You also could try this [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) which ads css3 tag support for IE6 to IE8

Answer (score 0):

This may not work for you, but if you're needing rounded corners and all four corners are the same radius, you can make it work with CSS3 PIE:

http://css3pie.com/

Again, this only works if **all** your corners are the same radius.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you have dismissed JavaScript as an option is because you don't think a JavaScript framework would support IE6, then have you checked out RaphaelJS (http://raphaeljs.com/)?

RaphaelJS is a graphics library which supports all major browsers **including** IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at another pure CSS solution for rounded corners that does not require images or JavaScript. 
http://www.spiffycorners.com/